Orthonormal Basis of subspaces of inner product spaces
I want to show the following:
Let W be a subspace of the inner product space V. Then W has an orthonormal-Basis that is subset of a orthonormal-Basis of V.
So if V was finite the statement could be proven with Gram-Schmidt process.
But in case of infinite demensional V I am missing an idea to proof it

Infinite dimensional inner product spaces need not have orthonormal Hamel bases. Either you are talking about Hilbert bases in the infinite dimensional case, or you are only working with finite dimensional spaces.
